# Can words before quotative と have 2 pitch accents?

Tags: pitch-accent

In 「角が3あるので三角と言います」:

- The dictionary pitch of 三角 is Atamadaka (`SAnkaku`)
- According to OJAD, く followed by a と should lead to the く being devoiced (`SAnkak_to`)

Yet, at 22s of https://youtu.be/oXlUnvr52jg?t=22, the speaker pretty clearly says "SAnkaKUto", which gives 三角 two accents, and removes its devoiced vowel.

Is this normal and/or part of some general pitch rule phenomenon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it (and this is definitely something I've observed a lot myself), the so-called "quotative" と generally* creates an accent kernel before it, i.e. you get 〇＼と.

Apparently there's no(t always a) need to raise the 〇 mora (whereas usually there's a small rise on "regular" accent kernels), just to drop *after* it (as you move to the と). The clearly raised く here sounds to me like it was a matter of intonation and/or a result of hyper-enunciation (but then again, what do *I* know).

The (re-)introduction of voicing is just a thing that sometimes happens when an accent falls on a devoiced mora. Devoiced morae carry no vocal pitch, which has the effect of obscuring any accent that falls on them (HL becomes _L). Sometimes voicing is (subconsciously) reintroduced to make the accent clearer.

- Sources: [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSlRA.jpg), [two](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/w700mk/comment/ihj20ti/?context=8), [2.5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-vQqcyUkdU&t=5051s) (up to 1:31:08)

*I say "generally" because, as you can see in the first source above, both はな＼すと and はなす＼と are given to be valid. My *assumption* is that, usually, you won't have to choose between two alternatives, but will rather realise *both* the word's accent *and* the downstep before the と (as with 三角と here). It's just that in the case of a [-2] word like 話す, realising both accents would require two consecutive downsteps, which might sound awkward / be tricky to pull off / be impossible(??). Again though, just guesswork.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer.